# Is there a way to see non forked repos only on github?

Tags: git, github

I have found a way to see all the forked repos, but how do I see only my own repos. That I created myself, didn't fork or anything.

Comment: I believe that's the `type=source` selection. I don't know for sure.

Comment: Try ```user:<username>``` in the search box on top left corner. The results page will show all repos, PRs, comments etc.

Comment: didn't work i tried

Comment: Can you share your result by updating your question with the result screenshot?

Comment: For ex. https://github.com/search?q=user%3Agithub lists all the repos created by user ```github``` under "Repositories" tab. Change the user name and check results.

Comment: they only show public repos, right?

Answer (score 5):

Here is how one can get github to display only their own repos that they created and which weren't forked from another user.

Step 1. Go to your profile icon in the right upper corner (at least that's where it is on the desktop - could be different on mobile) and click on "**Your repositories**" in the drop-down menu:

[image: Your repositories]

Step 2. Once the new page is loaded, select "**Sources**" in the "Type" drop-down menu:

[image: Sources]

And you get only the repositories that you created and not forked.

So in my case the direct URL is: https://github.com/stas00?tab=repositories&type=source

---

If the goal is to find someone else's "source" repositories, as suggested by @Mohana-Rao, use the URL:

`https://github.com/search?q=user:USERNAME&type=repositories`

after replacing `USERNAME` with the desired github username.

Note that this approach shows *Archived* repos too, whereas the first link doesn't. So if I use this method to list [my source repos](https://github.com/search?q=user%3Astas00&type=repositories) I get a slightly longer list here, as I have a few archived repos in my account.